# mongo db group-order

Tags: php, mongodb, group-by, mongo-collection, nosql

i want to mongodb query this sql query's:

```
select x,y,message,foo from messege where x=1 and y=1 group by x,y order by _id DESC
```

but with :

MongoCollection::group

can anyone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214406/how-to-group-by-with-mongodb?rq=1

Comment: I'm confused by the "order by" part of the query - you will only have a single result since you are grouping by a single value (x and y both 1) - are you sure this is the SQL you really want?   There is no aggregation here.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky 
yes, i test it on mysql

Comment: Could you post the result please?  I don't see how this can possibly return more than one row.

Answer (score 1):

For this

```
select a,b,sum(c) csum from coll where active=1 group by a,b
```

The respective is

```
db.coll.group(
           {key: { a:true, b:true },
            cond: { active:1 },
            reduce: function(obj,prev) { prev.csum += obj.c; },
            initial: { csum: 0 }
            });
```

You cannot sort the results you get from group, you can use sort for find like this for desc -1 , 1 for asc : .sort({"_id":-1}) desc

check this http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group

Comment: How can you add sort by _id when that's not part of your output?

Comment: where to add '.sort()' . group return object and array, not cursor. i want to get last records that suited where. not sort desc

Comment: Well you cannot sort the results you get with group, you can do it client side or use mapReduce http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce

Comment: you absolutely CAN sort results you get back with group - you just can't sort them by key that's not there, same as SQL