# MongoDB ODM How do I group by a certain field with map/reduce?

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I have a collection of documents that I want to query by a certain field called `location`, sort them by a `pos` field, and only return the highest value for each `pos` field.

So the query right now looks something like this:

```
$locations = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

   $results = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('\App\Document\Test')
        ->select('id', 'word', 'pos','change', 'title', 'coll_at', 'location')
        ->field('location')->in($locations)
        ->sort('location', 'asc')
        ->sort('pos', 'asc')
        ->getQuery()->execute();
```

But because there can be multiple entries for a specific `location` each with different `pos`, I then have to create a foreach loop to manipulate the data afterwards. In this scenario, I could take that shortcut just altering the data after it's returned, but I have other scenarios where it isn't efficient at all to do that. So I created this smaller scenario to try and figure out how to either use Doctrine ODM's `group` query, or even map & reduce it. Not sure the best way to. I see lots of examples of getting a running total, etc.

So how would I create a query to get the highest numerical value in the `pos` field for each specific `location`? Knowing that there can be multiple documents with the same `location` but a different `pos` value. And on top of that, have all the fields for the selected record that I have listed above in the `->select()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of grouping with Map Reduce you can group with:

- group() or in Doctrines case `distinct`: [How to "Group By" with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214406/how-to-group-by-with-mongodb)
- the aggregation framework using `$group`: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/

Do note that I believe the default implementation of Doctrines distinct actually works on the old `group()` command for MongoDB which is basically an MR wrapped however:

> So how would I create a query to get the highest numerical value in the pos field for each specific location

That might work, however if not then you will need to use the aggregation framework, however in Doctrine this is a little harder since they don't seem to have a true helper that links into the rest of their framework for it: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/issues/165 so you must the `command` function to run it.

#### Edit

I am a bit of a Doctrine noob myself so this is taken from examples:

```
$connection = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getConnection();
$mongo = $connection->getMongo();
if(!$mongo){
    $connection->connect();
    $mongo = $connection->getMongo();
}
$db = $mongo->selectDB('test_database');
$aggregate_results = $db ->command(array( 
            "aggregate" => "my_collection",
            "pipeline" => 
                array( 
                    array( '$group' => array( 'location' => '$location', 'pos' => array('$sum' => '$pos'))),
                    array( '$sort' => array( "pos" =>1 ) )
                )
        ));
```

This will run the aggregation for you, it won't be exactly what your looking for I don't think but play around with it.

Comment: Yeah I tried distinct, but that just returns a list of keywords. I was hoping to get the entire document returned. I am not opposed to using `command`. I would have the slightest clue how to write my query with it though. Any examples?

Comment: Sorry I only just remembered the reply, did you find what you were looking for in the end?

Comment: Not really. I found a work around doing a bunch of smaller queries, but my optimal result would be to use the group command, or map reduce. Being so new, I wasn't sure how to write/start using command.

Comment: Ok I have added a working example hopefully :) it is untested

Comment: Thanks for doing that! It doesn't have to be doctrine, using the php mongo driver & command functions is sufficient as well, especially if Doctrine doesn't support it yet. Thank you, I will try it out.

Comment: Yea doctrine doesn't truly support it but in that case if your using 1.3 of the php driver you actually have an aggregation helper on the mongo collection: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php but yea this would be outside of Doctrine

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Sammaye's answer. Doctrine ODM does support group queries:

http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#group-queries